# How to take the last 1 before a 2

Tags: r, dplyr, data.table

I have a data frame such like

```
id               state                  time
1                 1                      2017-10-01 07:01:00
1                 1                      2017-10-01 09:01:00  
1                 1                      2017-10-01 09:05:00  
1                 1                      2017-10-01 09:10:00  
1                 2                      2017-10-01 09:15:00  
1                 2                      2017-10-01 09:20:00  
1                 1                      2017-10-01 09:25:00  
1                 1                      2017-10-01 09:30:00
1                 1                      2017-10-01 12:42:00  
1                 1                      2017-10-01 12:45:00  
1                 1                      2017-10-01 12:50:00 
1                 1                      2017-10-01 12:55:00  
1                 2                      2017-10-01 01:35:00
1                 2                      2017-10-01 01:40:00
1                 2                      2017-10-01 01:45:00
```

So this data frame has a sequence of state change for different ids.From this data table I would like to find the last 1 state time before every state 2 for each id by also considering time difference threshold as 1 hour.

So basically the result would be something like

```
id                  state2time                      laststate1time
___                 ___________                    _________________
1              2017-10-01 09:15:00                2017-10-01 09:01:00        
1              2017-10-01 01:35:00                2017-10-01 12:42:00
```

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: 2017-10-01 12:42:00   is not 1 hour before 2017-10-01 12:42:00

Comment: @G5W What do you mean? I am breaking after 2017-10-01 09:30:00  intead of taking 2017-10-01 09:25:00 as the laststate1 time

Comment: Please try to explain your threshold criterion more clearly. At the moment it is hard to follow what you mean.

Comment: On the second row of your expected result, `laststate1time` is actually 11 hours and 7 minutes _after_ the `state2time`

Comment: Are you sure that `time` is of class `POSIXct`? It appears to me if you are using a 12 hour clock instead of a 24 hour clock. Please, [edit] your question and post the result of `dput(your_dataframe)`. Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If we assume that the OP has used a 12 hour clock instead of a 24 hour clock we can correct the times `01:35:00` to `13:35:00`, etc.

The OP has requested

> From this data table I would like to find the last 1 state time before every state 2 for each id by also considering time difference threshold as 1 hour.

Looking at the expected result (after above correction) my interpretation of OP's requirements are:

1. Find the first appearance of state 2 after state 1.
2. Go back in time one hour and pick the next state 1 event after that time

We need to find the *state 1 event with minimum time* for which the condition
*state2time - threshold <= laststate1time & laststate1time < state2time*    holds.

So, the title *last 1 before a 2* is misleading.

One possible solution is using a *non-equi join* of the subset of state 1 events with the subset of "first" state 2 events:

```
library(data.table)
threshold <- 1*60*60
setDT(DF)[, ts := time][state == 1L][
  DF[, sn := rleid(state)][
    state == 2, .(t2 = first(time), t1 = first(time) - threshold), by = .(id, sn)], 
  on = .(id, ts >= t1), .(state2time  = first(t2), laststate1time = first(time)), 
  by = .EACHI, nomatch = 0L][, -"ts"]
```

> ```
>    id          state2time      laststate1time
> 1:  1 2017-10-01 09:15:00 2017-10-01 09:01:00
> 2:  1 2017-10-01 13:35:00 2017-10-01 12:42:00
> ```

#### Caveat

There is an implicit assumption that each streak of state 1 events takes more than one hour. So, above code doesn't make any attempt to assure that the found state 1 event belongs to the immediately preceeding streak of state 1 events before the change to state 2. The OP has to specify the expected result in this case.